# @ApiImplicitQuery swagger - can't configure 'enum'

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, nestjs

You can see in the [nest swagger documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/swagger) how to configure enums, but it isn't working.

```
import {SwaggerEnumType} from '../types/swagger-enum.type';

export declare const ApiImplicitQuery: (metadata: {
    name: string;
    description?: string;
    required?: boolean;
    type?: 'String' | 'Number' | 'Boolean' | any;
    enum?: SwaggerEnumType;
    isArray?: boolean;
    collectionFormat?: "csv" | "ssv" | "tsv" | "pipes" | "multi";
}) => MethodDecorator;
```

Above you can see what I've changed in the code of the swagger module. Below you can see my code.

```
 @ApiImplicitQuery({name: "orderBy", enum: ['Admin', 'Moderator', 'User']})
    @ApiResponse({status: 200, description: "Successful getting registration list for admin"})
    @Get('registrations/list')
    public async getAdmin(@Req() req, @Res() res: Response,
                          @Query('page') page: number,
                          @Query('perPage') perPage: number,
                          @Query('orderBy') orderBy: UserRole = UserRole.User,
                          @Query('orderDir') orderDir: number
    ) {
        try {
            let token = await getCompaignIdFromAdminToken(req.headers['authorization']);
            let helper: HelperClass = new HelperClass();
            await helper.isUserAdmin(token);
            let users = await this.adminFacade.getAllUsersList(orderBy, orderDir);
            let entity = await this.adminFacade.parseRegistrationUsersList(users);
            let pagePar = (page) ? page : 0;
            let perPagePar = (perPage) ? perPage : users.length;
            let response = await returnResponseByPageAndPerPageValues(entity, pagePar, perPagePar);
            res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({response: response, entries: users.length});
        } catch (err) {
            errorResponse(res, err.message, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }

export enum UserRole {
    Admin = 'Admin',
    Moderator = 'Moderator',
    User = 'User'
}
```

And below you can see the generated swagger docs:
[image: Sample Image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Version v5.2.0 was just published! :-)

Answer (score 2):

## Update August 18

The pull request was just merged and is available in version `v5.2.0`.

## Original post

The [pull request](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/pull/102) introducing `enum` support for `ApiImplicitQuery` is not yet merged, hence the feature is not yet available. Unfortunately, the docs were updated too early:

> The doc is already update but not the code.

Follow the pull request to get notified when the feature will be available. Then you can update the `@nestjs/swagger` package.

Comment: I already have used it . Thanks) I also want to know when will be available file uploadings by swagger. I mean how to attach a file in payload by using this library?If u have an answer , will be appreciate it .

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your correctly. Do you want to have a file upload endpoint in general or do you want an existing one documented in your swagger docs? I'd recommend to open a new question and describe your requirement in more detail. Someone else might find this useful as well. :-)

If your enum problem is solved, you can mark one of the answers as accepted, so that others can see that his problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer and also I want this to be seen a bit more explicitly than a comment.

I am the author of the PR for this feature. I submitted the PR even before submitting the PR for the related portion on the Documentations. However, the related docs' PR was merged without the implementation PR being merged. It has been over a month and I haven't heard anything from Kamil (NestJS's author). I assume he is just too busy at the moment as there are only two people working on the whole framework: Kamil himself and ThomRick (NestCLI).

I hope, with enough requests and pressure, Kamil would actually look at the PRs on `@nestjs/swagger`. For now, I'd suggest you to handle your `Controller` to expect an *exact* `string` unfortunately.

Comment: Could you let me know here when it will be working? It is very needed for our test team. Yes, we can work without enums) But it is much easier to test smth if we have enums working.  Appreciate your help

Comment: Just want to update, PR was merged as of 40 minutes ago (https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/pull/102)